# Google Sheets - linked via importrange and inserting a new row

Tags: google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets:

- A budget sheet, with estimated costs and actual costs
- A cost tracking sheet, with the actual costs and reference to receipts

Currently I am importing the 'actual costs' in the budget sheet, by referencing rows from the 'actual costs' in the tracking sheet

So my budget sheet references the cost tracking sheet this way:
=(importrange("spreadsheet_key","sheet_name!I76"))

This works fine, however, if I insert a new row into my cost tracking sheet above some of the values I am already referencing, it will not dynamically update.

So if I insert a new row above:
=(importrange("spreadsheet_key","sheet_name!I76"))

I then have to manually change it in the other sheet to:
=(importrange("spreadsheet_key","sheet_name!I77"))

Is anyone aware of a way I can link two sheets and still be able to insert rows without this breaking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the range reference with the Address function. This produces a string representing the target range.

```
=importrange("spreadsheet_key", address(row('sheet_name'!76:76), column(I:I), 4, true, "sheet_name"))
```

Adding or deleting a row above row 76 on the sheet_name worksheet will adjust the range address accordingly.

Comment: Hello Jeeped :) Thank you for your help so far and for pointing me in the right direction. I am reading about the Address function online now. Currently I am still having some problems, as it doesn't recognize the first sheet name. I have replicated it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8wPicVyfs98QXRXRCHZoq-Y6Uoi75Iv8WitGja4Pic/edit?usp=sharing (budget) and https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YclB3V3817Q-RGwuzrOXoZkarwFszaTqwUFurtYtLVo/edit?usp=sharing (cost tracking).

Comment: oh! My solutions were for two different worksheets within the same workbook. Can that be used? If not, I may be able to look into a two worksheet in two workbooks solution later but not right now.

Comment: No worries, I appreciated your help and you've given me some interesting things to read about online. No rush, I'll see if I can figure it out too :) I should have been clearer in my original post. Thanks again!